# want to create Spring boot project in Eclipse IDE

Tags: spring-boot

I want to create a Spring MVC using Spring Boot in Eclipse IDE, but I am not able to find the 'Spring Starter Project' link in eclipse. How can I create a Spring Boot project in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Spring Tool Suite to your Eclipse or if you are using a new installation of Eclipse it is recommended to start with a fresh Spring Tool Suite installation.

https://spring.io/tools/sts/all